# Correlation and multiple random variables

Tags: probability

I'm currently working on this exercise:

> Suppose the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and
>   identically distributed. Let $Z = aX + Y$. If the correlation
>   coefficient between $X$ and $Z$ is $\frac13$ , then what is the value of the
>   constant **a** ?

My book says that the Convariance is defined as $Cov(X,Y) = (EXY) - (μxμy)$

So I know that $Cov(XZ) = 1/3$, how do I find the PDF from here? And what does it mean to be independent and identically distributed?

Comment: Are you sure that the "correlation coefficient" is supposed to be $13$? A correlation coefficient $\rho$ must satisfy $|\rho|<1$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, it was supposed to be 1/3

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are independent so $Cov(X,Y)=0$. It is $Cov(X,Z) = 1/3$.

Comment: thank you, I fixed that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independent and identically distributed (or iid.) is an important thing to understand. It just means what it says however: $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables, which share the same distribution. In particular, $EX=EY$, $VX=VY$, and so on. An example would be two coin tosses; independent of each other, but having the same probability of heads/tails.

Also, it is the correlation coefficient, not the covariance, that is $1/3$. We have
$$
Corr(X,Z):=\frac{Cov(X,Z)}{\sqrt{VXVZ}}=\frac13
$$
We can work out:
$$
VZ = V(aX+Y) = a^2VX+VY = (a^2+1)VX
$$
and
$$
Cov(X,Z)= Cov(X,aX+Y)
= aCov(X,X) + Cov(X,Y) = aVX+0
$$
I skipped some justifications that you can hopefully fill in. Can you finish from here?

If you want to work from the definitions $Cov(X,Y)=EXY-EXEY$ and $VX=EX^2-(EX)^2$, then remember that $E$ is linear, and that $E(XY)=EXEY$ for **independent** variables. (But I don't recommend that, since you should have the linearity theorems for variance and covariance available).

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality assume $X,\,Y$ have mean $0$ and variance $1$, so $Z$ has variance $1+a^2$ and $\Bbb EXZ=\Bbb E(aX^2+XY)=a$. Hence $\frac13=\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\implies a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$.